# Saving images with Magick

Tags: r, image-processing, magick-r-package

I'm trying to automate adding my signature to my photos using the magick package - but I'm having problems saving them.

Here's my code:

```
file_list <- dir(".", pattern = "*.png")

mySig <- image_read("~/Desktop/sig1.png")
mySig <- mySig %>% image_resize("300x300")

newPhotos <- 
  for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
    img <- image_read(file_list)
    photoSig <- img %>% 
      image_composite(mySig, gravity = "southeast", offset = "+20+20")
    newName <- as.character(paste0("New_", file_list))
    image_write(photoSig, newName, format = "png")
  }
```

And I get the following error regardless of the script being in or out of a loop:

```
Error in file(con, "wb") : invalid 'description' argument
```

On top of this - even when I don't automate the name and just have the output called `"test"` or something - it only saves one of the photos and not all of them. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I dont know if this is the / an issue but you are looping through a vector of length  `file_list` but then calling `file_list` without indexing it i.e. `file_list[i]`

Comment: @user20650 you're amazing! I was hoping it would be something small that I overlooked! The code works fine now

Comment: Good stuff ....